# Django. Использование ldap авторизации и групп пользователей в разных доменах AD

Tags: python, django, ldap

Требуется настроить авторизацию пользователей в django по ldap из разных доменов.

Например: Пользователь при авторизации вводит user@domain1 - требуется пройти авторизацию по ldap с доменом domain1 и получить список групп пользователя в AD и далее оперировать этим списком (Данные для подключения к конкретному домену будут находиться в модели)

Подкиньте, пожалуйста, идей, как этот функционал можно реализовать.

Comment: https://blog.thomastoye.be/python-ldap-authentication-with-microsoft-active-directory-46661bebc483

Comment: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind.html https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema.html?highlight=memberof#operational-attributes

Comment: Вы видимо не полностью прочли мой вопрос. Требуется реализация авторизации в зависимости от указанного пользователем домена (Доменов большое количество, для каждого указывать настройки привязки не вариант. Данные нужно брать из базы)